# Error in express app when using Connect-redis to store session data "Type Error Client.get is not a function"

Tags: express, redis, node-redis, connect-redis

I'm quite new to using express. I'm using express, react, and mongodb to create a full stack app. When storing the sessionID on the Express server, I'm using a redis store with the "redis" and "connect-redis" packages.

For the most part this structure works, however, there is an error that occurs when I try to log out that messes up the server.

I can log in (create profiles, get posts etc) without any errors but for some reason once I try to log out, I get this TypeError: client.get is not a function Error. Even if I try restarting my two servers, this error message keeps on popping up in my terminal. Furthermore, once I start getting these TypeError functions, even if I restart my servers, whenever I log in (/ do any requests of an API endpoint) I now get the error message "TypeError: client.set is not a function". I can log in fine, but this message pops up. Then when I try to log out I get the client.get error and the client.set error as well as a response status of 500.

I'd be extremely grateful if anyone has any insight in solving this error. And perhaps, Redis is not the best fast-querying database that I should use to store sessions.

Some additional details:

- I installed redis, connect redis using the command "npm i redis" and "npm i connect-redis"
- I will post my router orders, the error I get in the terminal, my logout function, index.js, redis set up, and session set up
- The error when logging out does not get caught in my err if statement in the logout function. The error gets caught in my global error catching function

**Session Implementation**

/myapp/middleware/session.js

```
import session from "express-session";
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";
import RedisStore from "connect-redis";

// Database
import redisClient from "../db/redis.js"
 
// Initialize store. 
let redisStore = new RedisStore({ 
    client: redisClient,
    prefix: "myapp:",
  })

// Connecting Session with Redis server
export default session(
    {
        store: redisStore,
        secret: 'SOME_PASSWORD', 
        resave: false, 
        saveUninitialized: false, the session,
        name: "sessionID",
        cookie: {      
            secure: false, 
            httpOnly: true, 
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30 , 
        } 
    }
);
```

/myapp/db/redis.js

**Redis Implementation**

```
import {createClient} from 'redis'; 
import session from "express-session";

// Error
import ApiError from "../error/ApiError.js"


// Configuration of Redis Instance

// Initialize client.
  let redisClient = createClient(); 

  try{
    console.log("Creating client")
    redisClient.connect()
  } catch(err){
    console.error("Redis error: ", err)
    throw ApiError.redisError("Error with Redis")
  }
  
export default { redisClient }
```

/myapp/index.js

**Index.js Implementation**

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from "cors";
import authServer from "./routes/authServer.js";
import session from "./middleware/session.js";
import redisClient from "./db/redis.js"


appAuthServer.use(express.json());
appAuthServer.use(session);

appAuthServer.use(cors())

appAuthServer.use('/users', authServer)

appAuthServer.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Route not found", 404)
})

appAuthServer.listen(AUTH_SERVER_PORT, ()=>{
  console.log(`Auth Server is running on port: ${AUTH_SERVER_PORT}`)
})

appAuthServer.use(apiErrorHandler)



export default { 
  appAuthServer
};
```

**Sub router implementation**
/myapp/routers/posts.js

```
const router = express.Router(); 

// Allows express to use json 
router.use(express.json());


router.post('/createProfile', authController.createProfile);

router.post('/login', authenticateLogin, authController.login)

router.use(authenticateSession)

router.post('/logout', authController.logout)

router.delete("/deleteAccount", authController.deleteAccount);
```

**Log out function implementation**

```
function logout(req, res, next){
    console.log("In the log out function")
    req.session.destroy(req.sessionID, (err) => {
        if (err) { 
            next(ApiError.internal("Error in logging out"))
        }
        console.log("Destroyed session")
    })
    return res.redirect('/');
}
```

**Terminal errors**

[Stackerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jglgc.png)

[StackError Number#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V072J.png)

Things I've tried:

- Downloading and redownloading redis and connect-redis
- Restart server multiple times
- [Double checking connect-redis documentation to make sure my implementation is correct](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis)

All of these things I've tried didn't change the behavior of my program.